# Whitespace between DIVs disrupting the layout

Tags: css, html

Let's say I have the following HTML/CSS to have two columns of DIVs, each 50 pixels wide.

```
<div style="width:100px;margin:0px;">
    <div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">A</div><!-- HERE -->
    <div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">B</div>
</div>
```

In this snippet of code, if I do not have any whitespace between two inner divs (i.e. where `<!-- HERE -->` is):

```
<div style="...">
    <div style="..."></div><div style="..."></div>
</div>
```

Then the HTML is rendered in two columns, as expected. However, if I have any whitespace between them, they're not rendered side-by-side, because the whitespace character take up nonzero width.

The obvious solution to this is to not have any whitespaces between the inner DIVs, however, I'm using HTML autoformatter to format my HTML code, and it automatically inserts whitespace between the two inner DIVs.

Is there any solution to this, so that the two inner DIVs are rendered as expected, even when there are whitespaces between them?

Comment: you can position them so that they are touching each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;` to the `100px container`.

No `floats`, `positioning`, etc.

```
<div style="width:100px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;">
    <div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;background:#efefef;">A a</div><!-- HERE --><div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;background:#ccc;">B b</div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yQ6L/2/

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` will not eliminate the gap, though.

Comment: yeah, you've got to add word-spacing to that as well. Answer updated. Essentially, A and B divs are two words now with the inline-block attribute.

Comment: well I'll be! I didn't know there was a `word-spacing` property. How well is it supported across browsers (ie IE6)?

Comment: Looks like IE6 was the first version to support it. You're in luck(?) :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Checkout second sentence of "Introduction"

Comment: thanks! This is a much better solution than the `font-size` hacks.

Comment: I understand using `white-space: nowrap`, and `word-spacing` seemed like the key, but when I use `word-spacing: 0;` in what I think is a similar situation (four divs, each 25%), it does not do what I expect. To get the desired effect (no visible space between divs that have whitespace between them), I am required to use `word-spacing: -4px;` or `word-spacing: -1em;` (?), which seems hacky :-\ -- Any clue why this might be different? (developing for IE8+ only) Should I ask this in a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
div style="width:100px;margin:0px;">
<div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">A</div><!-- 
--><div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">B</div>
```

or if you're using php etc

```
    div style="width:100px;margin:0px;">
<div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">A</div><? /*
*/ ?><div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;">B</div>
```

dunno if that'd help

Comment: This answer made me smile, lovely hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can float the inner divs and add `overflow: hidden` to the outer:

```
<div style="width:100px;margin:0px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="width:50px; float: left;">A</div>
    <div style="width:50px; float: left;">B</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3yQ6L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block will behave like an image, or a text character for that matter, so the space between them will be dependent on font size.

You could try to float them to the left, or you could try to set the font size very low. You could also try a negative left margin on the second box.